# Can't install basemap package in datalab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to run a script within a Google datalab Jupyter notebook that requires basemap, but I can't install this package. Yelsayed has pointed out that the module requires several dependencies, but even after building these the module won't install.

Here are the dependencies that I believe need to be installed:

```
!pip install Cython

!apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc

!pip install pyproj

!pip install GEOS
```

These install without event. Finally basemap itself which again Yelsayed has pointed out needs to be done with the following:

```
!pip install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz
```

This takes time to install and seems to show promise, but ultimately it gets to 99% installed and then outputs "killed":

```
Collecting https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz
Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz (129.7MB)
99% |############################### | 129.7MB 154kB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

The "Killed" at end seems to indicate it ultimately hasn't worked. It does this reliably, re-attempting the above call fails in the same way. In any case I gave importing the module a go, but still get the same error:

```
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

Why is this happening and how do you successfully install basemap in this environment?

Comment: can you use conda? this will be easy w/ conda

Comment: I've not come across conda yet, how would that work?

Comment: `conda install basemap` https://conda.io/docs/intro.html

Comment: Also, did you take the error message's advice and install the spatial dependencies?

Comment: I get a similar error message when I try to install the suggested dependencies. I'll work on installing conda and trying your suggestion above.

Comment: I'm struggling to get conda to run from within the datalab notebook, it's definitely possible is it?

Comment: For example. conda --version shows the version when run from the command line but shows "conda: not found" when run from within the datalab notebook

Comment: install it from the command line then

Comment: I have done, it only doesn't work from the notebook, I don't follow why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like `basemap` is hosted on PyPI due to size. Look at the install instructions on https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.

You can just use their direct link for v1.0.7:

`!pip install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz`

EDIT

Here's some more breakdown of installing the prerequisites as well, run all the following in notebook cells:

#### GEOS:

Your best bet is to install it directly from `apt` to avoid versioning issues. You can do:

```
%bash
apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-c1 libgeos++-dev
```

#### pyproj, pyshp

You then install the python dependencies, using pip easily:

```
%bash
pip install pyproj pyshp
```

#### basemap

Then you can install the basemap package using the link above:

```
%bash
!pip install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz
```

You can then import the basemap class:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems very promising when this runs, it takes a while to install, but at the end it say "killed" and the won't load I get "ImportError: No module named basemap" I'll post a fuller trace in my question.

Comment: @goose do you have all the requirements installed as well? on their github repo there's a list of at least three things that you need to install that don't exist as part of Datalab

Comment: Thanks again for all the help @yelsayed. I hadn't spotted that. I've working through it now, just struggling to install pyproj

Comment: well it's not easy to install lots of requirements through the notebook interface, we're aware of this. hopefully in the future there would be a way to put your requirements in a custom script that is loaded when the Datalab instance starts. you can open an issue here: github.com/googledatalab/datalab if you have a specific use case.

Comment: Thanks @Yelsayed. I'm not sure if it's a use case, but I've posted what I'm stuck on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098899/cant-install-pyproj-module-in-google-datalab-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Unfortunately @Yelsayed after installing pyproj, GEOS and Cython the package basemap still doesn't install. It looks like it has, it gets to 99% as per above but ultimately says that it's killed. Attempts to load the module then fail.

Comment: @goose you're probably having issues with some of the dependencies. take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: thanks very much for coming back to me. I ran the above, also adding in apt-utils. I ran the basemap installation with the %bash and got "bash: line 1:  1453 Killed". Running with an exclamation mark and without the %bash returns the same output as before, it seems promising, but ends on killed. The dependencies install without warning with the exception of a notification about apt-utils that I went back and installed.

Comment: interesting. it worked fine for me. if you want to play around and experiment, an easier way is to open a shell session inside the docker container running Datalab. if you're running the container locally, you can do `docker ps` to get the container ID, then `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to get a shell, then try installing from there. also, do you see the package downloading then failing to install?

Comment: That's interesting to know, when installing from the shell as you directed I get exactly he same result. As you say, it downloads and fails to install with the output listed above.

Comment: I think I've managed to install it. Using the shell that you told me about, I cloned & installed directly from git. It now loads. Thanks again for your help! It may be worth adding this to the solution above for others who follow.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem writing this piece of code in your Google Cloud Datalab Notebook

```
! apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated --fix-missing install python-mpltoolkits.basemap python-numpy python-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

Basemap doesn't come with the google datalab out of the box.

As of Feb 2019, this works on a fresh google datalab:

**Step 1: Install Pre-requisites**

- `!apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated build-essential libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos++-dev`

Note: I tried yelsayed's example, however my datalab couldn't find libgeos-3.4.2 and libgeos-c1 was deprecated at the time I ran it. I updated these values to 3.5.0 and c1v5 and it worked. I also had to add the allow unauthenticated tags part.

- `!pip install pyproj pyshp`

**Step 2: Install the whole package**

- `!pip install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz`

**Step 3: Check the package has been installed correctly**

- `!pip freeze`

**Step 4: Import the module**

- `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`