# Can't install pyproj module in Google Datalab Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to install pyproj within a Google Datalab Jupyter notebook as a required dependency for the basemap library. I've tried two methods, needless to say neither has worked.

**Method 1: Cloning from git**

```
!git clone https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git
```

Outputs:

```
Cloning into 'pyproj'...
remote: Counting objects: 2811, done.
remote: Total 2811 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2810
Receiving objects: 100% (2811/2811), 5.65 MiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1951/1951), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

And install command:

```
!python ./pyproj/setup.py install
```

Outputs:

```
using bundled proj4..
unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyproj/setup.py", line 86, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 122, in _compile
    raise CompileError, msg
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**Method 2: Using pip**

```
!pip install pyproj
```

Outputs:

```
Collecting pyproj
Using cached pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
using bundled proj4..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-FcWGXL/pyproj/setup.py", line 72, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 122, in _compile
    raise CompileError, msg
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-FcWGXL/pyproj/
```

What method can be used to install pyproj from within a Datalab Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need gcc for it to build. Do `apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc` in a cell then try the `pip install pyproj` again.

Comment: This worked. I bow down to your Python knowledge. Thanks again for your help!